# Selenium fileupload path format issue

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I'M trying to upload a file via Selenium IDE, the path is the following:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("fileupload")).SendKeys("C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\TestPackages\\new-package\\0.0.1\\new-package.zip");
```

The query fails because the sendkey path is actually:

```
C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\TestPackages\ew-package\\0.0.1\ew-package.zip
```

Notice the \n disappear. How can I stop this?

Thanks

Comment: The path seems right. If you want a new line then you use "\n" but as you used "\\n" which prints or sends the two characters the '\' and the 'n'.

Answer (score 0):

I think the \n is disappearing because \n in a string means a new line

Do you need the double slashes or are you using that to escape the slash?

Try adding an extra slash like this:

```
{
C:\\\Users\\\myuser\\\Documents\\\Visual Studio 2010\\\Projects\\\TestPackages\\\\\new-package\\\0.0.1\\\\\new-package.zip    
}
```

Comment: Yes, the reason is because it is a new line.  tried your format, and it doesn't work. It simply gives adds the extra \ while removing the n.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a tricky one, and seems to be related only to selenium IDE. The way I fixed this is I edited the file path in the 'Source' tab instead of the "Table' tab.

It seems like the engine behind selenium ide would try to convert \n to 
. So I simply deleted the html tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following approach will fix the issue,

Instead of escape sequences use **@** like below. Format the file path same as like how it appears in Windows explorer,

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("fileupload")).SendKeys(@"C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestPackages\new-package\0.0.1\new-package.zip");
```

Comment: What does the '@' do in this situation?

Comment: '@' will handle the escape sequences and no need to explicitly mention it